# Allow users to add extra products/services in the cart

Tags: commerce, 9

The idea is to allow users to choose supplemental products right in cart (for example, insurance or assembly). Those are in no way related to main product type items.

I know there is the [Commerce Product Add-on](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pado) module, but there is no need to relate those extra products.

How can I achieve it in Commerce 2?

Answer (score 1):

If the supplemental products have no relationship to the main products, you can create a block that shows the supplemental products and then set that block to be shown on the cart page.

Comment: That somewhat worked. Now looking to replace "add to cart" button with checkbox, as it looks like easier way for user to select items.

Comment: @betarobot Follow-up questions should be posted as new questions because this is a Q&A site, not a forum.  Posting questions individually helps future visitors to the site check if their questions have already been asked.

Comment: Thanks for correction Patrick, now makes sense.